# What are these brackets?

Tags: framing

I’m doing a remodel and found these brackets attached to some of the studs. The home was built in 1902.

What are these brackets?

[image: Bracket 1]

[image: Bracket 2]

Comment: It looks like someone was stiffening up the structure, which seems to have been framed using some methods & materials that we wouldn't consider today.  If you are adding structural shear panels to the exterior of the building, that will stiffen it up a lot; but I wouldn't remove any of those metal fasteners without consulting an engineer.

Comment: It could be for earthquake resistance was the house bolted to the foundation?

Comment: Your profile indicates that you are in a quake-prone area (like, right on the San Andreas). Somebody at some point added those to strengthen against shaking. Some cities/counties/states have offered rebates for work like that, some mandate it for certain occupancies, some insurance companies charge more without it.

Comment: *10 hole angle bracket* gave me this : [build.com/product/summary](https://www.build.com/product/summary/1716924?uid=4058866&jmtest=gg-gbav2_4058866&inv=1&&source=gg-gba-pla_4058866!c1045496523!a48064345661!dc!ng&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkvbJl7GS7gIViIbACh3g8gMeEAQYAiABEgKeqfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: @Mazura that is exactly it. Great find !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are these brackets?

Those are galvanized steel brackets attached with timber screw fasteners.

As neither of these products were manufactured in 1902, it is safe to say that someone in the recent past added them to reinforce the structure.